# how to get picklist value in Rest API

Tags: rest-api, picklist

I am new in salesforce, I want know how to get the custom picklist value from REST API,

I get the all the picklist from below API

```
$this->instance_url//services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe
```

Now I want to get my custom picklist details in rest API, my custom picklist details name is

```
[maskType] => 
                    [name] => Product_Type__c
                    [nameField] => 
                    [namePointing] => 
                    [nillable] => 1
                    [permissionable] => 1
                    [picklistValues] => Array
                        (
)
```

I called the API like below but the error is displayed, please let me know how to get the picklist value

```
$this->instance_url/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_type__c/describe/picklistValues
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: i got an error as follows services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Product_type__c/describe/picklistValues` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}] in

Comment: There should be a picklist value property in raw json. Can you add your response json here ?

Comment: You can run the **instance_url//services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe** in workbench and then you get the raw json

Comment: this url work, instance_url//services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe  I want to get only  Product_type_c reponse only

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to get at this information through the REST API? If you're working in Apex, there's no need to callout to the REST API. If you're not working in Apex, knowing what language you _are_ working in would help give some context to the question.

Comment: Also, is `Product_Type__c` a custom object, or is it a custom field on `Opportunity`?

Comment: Product_Type__c  is custom object, This object value available from picklist, @Derek , I am not working APEX, It should integrate with php site, Thats why I am using rest API